# compute $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{n}{(n+i)(n^2+j^2)}$

Tags: limits, multiple-integral

$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{n}{(n+i)(n^2+j^2)}$

the form of limits reminds me $\iint\limits_{D} f(x,y)dxdy =  \lim\limits_{\lambda\to 0}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}f(x,y)dxdy$
$D=\{(x,y)|x\in [1,\infty],y\in [1,\infty]\}$

but that is all I can think about this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\lim\limits_{n\to \infty }\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{(n+i)(n^2+j^2)} = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty }\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{i}{n}}\right)\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{1+(\frac{j}{n})^2}\right)\frac{1}{n}
$$

and finally

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{i}{n}}\right)\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{1+(\frac{j}{n})^2}\right)\frac{1}{n} = \int_0^1\frac{d \xi}{1+\xi}\int_0^1\frac{d\eta}{1+\eta^2}=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln (2)
$$

Comment: how do you compute $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{1+\frac{i}{n}})\frac{1}{n}$, plz

Comment: Riemann integration! $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+\xi}d\xi$

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand how you can change $\sum_{i=1}^{n}$ to $\sum_{i=1}^\infty$ in your first sentence?